# Insertion Algorithm using new array in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to implement the sorting algorithm which takes the element and copies it to the to `new array` and sorts them in some manner. I know ,it is inefficient and old-fashioned one but the goal here is to improve algorithmic mindset. I am going to paste all the code, which is a bit extensive but leaves no gap behind.

The block, specifically to be fixed probably is the one which starts with `while not check`. i am trying worst-case scenario(reversed array).

So every time the index `j=0` and it starts to do swap from the beginning. I want it to do vice versa(to start from the end).

```
def swap(container, i, j):
    if container[i] != container[j]:
        container[i], container[j] = container[j], container[i]


def old_sort(container):
    new_arr = [0 for i in range(0, 20)]
    new_arr[0] = container[0]
    j = 0
    for i in range(1, len(container)):
        
        if len(new_arr) == 1 and container[i] < new_arr[j]:
            container[j+1] = container[i]
            
        
        while container[i] < new_arr[j]:
            j -=1
        
        if j < 0:
            j +=1
                
        tmp = container[i]
        index = j
        check = False
        
        while not check and j < len(new_arr) and container[j] != 0:
                new_arr[j+1] = new_arr[j]
                j +=1
                check = True
        
        check = False
            
        new_arr[index] = tmp
    
    return new_arr

container = [i for i in range(10, -1, -1)]
sorted_arr = old_sort(container)
print(sorted_arr)
```

**UPDATE:**

I have already pinpointed the problem without using second index. As i am setting `tmp=container[i]`, i have to compare it with previous element which is container[i-1] and then do swaps and at the end, set `tmp` to its correct location.

```
def old_sort(container):
    new_arr = [0 for i in range(0, 11)]
    new_arr[0] = container[0]
    

    for i in range(1, len(container)):
        tmp = container[i]
        
        while tmp < new_arr[i - 1] and i > 0:
            new_arr[i] = new_arr[i-1]
            i -=1
        
        if i < 0:
            i +=1
        new_arr[i] = tmp
    
    return new_arr

tests = [
        [11,9,29,7,2,15,28],
        [3, 7, 9, 11],
        [25, 22, 21, 10],
        [29, 15, 28],
        [6]
    ]

for elements in tests:
    new_arr = old_sort(elements)
    print(new_arr)
```

Output:

```
[2, 7, 9, 11, 15, 28, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 7, 9, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10, 21, 22, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
[15, 28, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]   
[6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Which sorting algorithm are you following?

Comment: @ubaidshaikh Insertion. But I have already  gave the solution.

Comment: Why do we need `new_arr`? Why not modify the `container` array itself?

Comment: I said it in the outline that "the goal is to improve algorithmic mindset".

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate from j as the last item, down to 0.  I'm not sure if you would then want to change what index you use for new_arr, maybe you want j-1.

```
j = len(new_arr) - 1
while not check and j >= 0 and container[j] != 0:
    new_arr[j + 1] = new_arr[j]
    j -= 1
    check = True
```